# Executing SQL query from VBA - run time error

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I try to execute the simplest and shortest query from VBA on SQL-Server using ADO. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub VBA_to_SQL()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MyServerName;Database=MyDataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cnn.Open

    If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
       Set rs = cnn.Execute("begin transaction insert_value; delete from dbo.MyTable;COMMIT TRANSACTION insert_value;")
        cnn.Close
        MsgBox "Got through!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry. No way today."
    End If
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error on the line `Set rs = cnn.Execute("begin transaction insert_value; delete from dbo.MyTable;;COMMIT TRANSACTION insert_value;")`
The error message is *Run-time error '-2147217908 (80040e31)'*

If I comment the error-causing line I manage to get through to the server. So the connection is established, however the query is not executed.

**Update** This code worked well for several days and all of a sudden stopped. Too bad!

Comment: I entered your [error code into Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Run-time+error+%27-2147217908+%2880040e31%29%27) and the prevailing theme seems to be "Timeout expired" on the Sql Command. If you execute your command in SSMS how long does it take?

Comment: The execution of the query takes less then a second.

Comment: That doesn't look like a transaction that returns a recordset to me.

Comment: @Rory what do you mean? What is the direction for me?

Comment: I mean it looks like you should use just: `cnn.Execute "begin transaction insert_value; delete from dbo.MyTable;;COMMIT TRANSACTION insert_value;"` without a recordset at all.

Comment: If you run it without the explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT TRANSACTION` do you still get the same error? With just a single statement inside these are redundant anyway.

Comment: @Rory This won't make any difference, since `adExecuteNoRecords` has not been specified `cnn.Execute()` will return a closed recordset, if `adExecuteNoRecords` had been specified then it would return `Nothing` - either way, although unnecessary assignment, it should not throw an error.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps: `cnn.BeginTrans: cnn.Execute "delete from dbo.MyTable;": cnn.committrans` then?

Comment: I still get the same error even if I reduce the string to `delete from dbo.MyTable` or change code to `cnn.Execute "delete from dbo.MyTable;"

Comment: As I updated my question - my VBA code worked well for several days and then it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the worm and crunched it. Running this on SQL Server helped. Thank you all for care.

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDataBaseName] 
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
CHECKPOINT;

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDataBaseName_log,0);

ALTER DATABASE [MyDataBaseName]
MODIFY FILE (NAME=MyDataBaseName_log,SIZE=8000MB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,FILEGROWTH=1000MB);
ALTER DATABASE [MyDataBaseName] 
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

Comment: So you ran out space in your file? Normally there is an ado errors collection that would tell you this (as the VBA error is pretty useless!)

Comment: Yes, the log file sometimes grows unexpectedly. I started monitoring its size to catch when it grows. But that is completely another issue not involved with ADO.